# Ajax-запросы к Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Когда я хочу работать с аутентификацией Devise с помощью Ajax-запросов, мне надо как-то переопределить встроенные action'ы Devise'a дабы он не слал мне в ответ страницу, на которую по умолчанию перенаправляет. Но в контроллерах я вижу только ссылку super. Как быть? Что делать?

Comment: Завести собственные контроллеры?

Comment: Если заводить их с нуля, то тогда едва ли не проще завести свой Devise

Comment: Почему с нуля. Можно наследовать контроллер девайза.

Comment: Так это и пытаюсь сделать, но у меня нет доступа к тому, что там происходит в его контроллерах, только через super, а мне этого мало

Comment: Исходный код девайза у вас точно есть. Ваши методы необязательно должны дополнять/оборачивать девайзовские, могут и замещать.

Comment: Ваша ситуация довольно распространенная. На самом деле, если хорошо поискать, то ответы на эти вопросы уже давно есть https://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/